# Seleccionar valores del campo XML en SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

Tengo una tabla en SQL que tiene dos campos (`id`, `xml`), solo mirando mi campo XML, la fila es así:

```
<Sheet1>
    <Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
    <Item_x0020_Number>VPJG7F-10849-BD</Item_x0020_Number>
    <Fecha>02/20 - 02/26</Fecha>
    <cantidad>2</cantidad>
</Sheet1>
<Sheet1>
    <Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
    <Item_x0020_Number>VPJG7F-10849-DD</Item_x0020_Number>
    <Fecha>02/20 - 02/26</Fecha>
    <cantidad>1</cantidad>
</Sheet1>
```

Me gustaría que se vieran en una tabla normal en SQL como esto:

```
Production line Item Number     Date   Cantidad 
L1B4            VPJG7F10849BD   02/20  2        
L1B4            VPJG7F10849DD   02/20  1
```

Teniendo los datos en una tabla poder hacer una consulta y seleccionar `L1B4` y que se sumen las cantidades 2 y 1, o me gustaría saber si hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo.

Comment: Me pareció una pregunta muy interesante, por tal movito me animé a responderla, pero recuerda, para futuros casos es importante poner los avances o los intentos que hayas realizado. La investigación previa hará que hagas es bien recibida y más usuarios se animarán a responder si tienes un caso y una falla muy específicos. Por cierto, había un error en tu XML, faltaba cerrar adecuadamente la etiqueta `Item_x0020_Number` del primer elemento.

Comment: Pondre el codigo que hize anteriormente y el error que me muestra

Comment: si tienes algún error solo sigue el código que te pasé :) ese ya funciona a la perfección :D

Comment: Muchas gracias n.n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El siguiente *script* te puede ayudar:

```
CREATE TABLE TablaXML (
    Id INT,
    ContenidoXML XML
)

INSERT INTO TablaXML (Id, ContenidoXML) VALUES (1, '<Sheet1><Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line><Item_x0020_Number>VPJG7F-10849-BD</Item_x0020_Number><Fecha>02/20 - 02/26</Fecha><cantidad>2</cantidad></Sheet1><Sheet1><Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line><Item_x0020_Number>VPJG7F-10849-DD</Item_x0020_Number><Fecha>02/20 - 02/26</Fecha><cantidad>1</cantidad></Sheet1>')

SELECT * FROM TablaXML

DECLARE @xml XML

SELECT @xml = ContenidoXML FROM TablaXML

SELECT  
       Tabla.Columna.value('Production_x0020_Line[1]', 'VARCHAR(64)') AS 'Production line',
       Tabla.Columna.value('Item_x0020_Number[1]', 'VARCHAR(64)') AS 'Item Number',
       Tabla.Columna.value('Fecha[1]', 'VARCHAR(64)') AS 'Date',
       Tabla.Columna.value('cantidad[1]', 'smallint') AS 'Quantity'
FROM   @xml.nodes('//Sheet1') Tabla(Columna)
```

Aquí puedes ver la <kbd>[demostración](http://rextester.com/LVX7556)</kbd> y sus resultados.